# Regex to leave desired string remaining and others removed

Tags: ruby, regex, regex-negation

In Ruby, what regex will strip out all but a desired string if present in the containing string? I know about `/[^abc]/` for characters, but what about strings?

Say I have the string `"group=4&type_ids[]=2&type_ids[]=7&saved=1"` and want to retain the pattern `group=\d`, if it is present in the string using only a regex?

Currently, I am splitting on `&` and then doing a select with matching condition `=~ /group=\d/` on the resulting enumerable collection. It works fine, but I'd like to know the regex to do this more directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply:
`part = str[/group=\d+/]`

If you want only the numbers, then:
`group_str = str[/group=(\d+)/,1]`

If you want only the numbers as an integer, then:
`group_num = str[/group=(\d+)/,1].to_i`

*Warning: `String#[]` will return `nil` if no match occurs, and blindly calling `nil.to_i` always returns `0`.*

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
$str =~ s/.*(group=\d+).*/\1/;
```

Comment: Given that Ruby's regex does not include newline for `.` this will only work for a single-line string. Further, you seem to have included some sort of _sed_ syntax instead of Ruby. (I'd downvote you, but I'm out for the day.)

Answer (score 1):

Typically I wouldn't really worry too much about a complex regex. Simply break the string down into smaller parts and it becomes easier:

```
asdf = "group=4&type_ids[]=2&type_ids[]=7&saved=1"

asdf.split('&').select{ |q| q['group'] } # => ["group=4"]
```

Otherwise, you can use regex a bunch of different ways. Here's two ways I tend to use:

```
asdf.scan(/group=\d+/) # => ["group=4"]
asdf[/(group=\d+)/, 1] # => "group=4"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
str.match(/group=\d+/)[0]
```